# Python Tkinter deiconify withdrawn window with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

Is there a way to withdraw a window and deiconify it using a keyboard shortcut? If I do something like: `root.bind("<Control-q>", lambda event: root.deiconify())`, it doesn't trigger when the window is withdrawn. If there isn't a way to do it with Tkinter, is there a module that works on Windows that will allow me to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way by using the keyboards module. The keyboards module globally binds keyboard events so it won't matter if your iconified window is no longer on focus.

See this link: [Is there a way to deiconify root window with keyboard binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547083/is-there-a-way-to-deiconify-root-window-with-keyboard-binding)