# Is there a way to deiconify root window with keyboard binding?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to find a way to deiconify the root window after it's been icononfied. Is this possible?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

value = True


def callback(_):
    global value
    if value:
        root.iconify()
        root.focus()
        value = False
    else:
        root.deiconify()
        value = True


root.bind('1', callback)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have the right idea, but you will need to get the command trigger from somewhere else because once you iconify the window it no longer listens for HID events. Perhaps look into the `keyboard` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Novel mentioned, we must use another module to always listen for keypress event.

```
import tkinter
import keyboard

root = tkinter.Tk()

def callback():
    if root.state() == "normal":
        root.iconify()
    else:
        root.deiconify()

keyboard.add_hotkey('1', callback)
root.mainloop()
```